# Getting External Log File From Powershell Into TeamCity

Tags: powershell, teamcity

So I have a log file that gets created from a SQLCMD call that is executed via TeamCity.  How do I get this log file to show up in the build log for TeamCity?

I can't find any documentation on ##teamcity on importing a text file into the log output that you see in TeamCity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the content of the external log file during the Build. For example:
type extetnal.log

Comment: Thank you for your response.  it worked for what I needed.